# Applying a local match/rewrite globally using recursion schemes

Tags: haskell, recursion-schemes

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, DeriveFoldable, TemplateHaskell,
    TypeFamilies, DeriveFunctor, DeriveTraversable #-}
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Functor.Foldable
import Data.Functor.Foldable.TH
import Data.Maybe
```

I want to rewrite a tree using a "local" rewriter:

```
data SKI = S | K | I | App SKI SKI deriving (Show)

makeBaseFunctor ''SKI

type Rewrite a = a -> Maybe a

match :: Rewrite SKI
match x = case x of
    App I x -> Just x
    _ -> Nothing
```

So I wrote `rewriteGlobal` function that applies the same `match` at different points in the tree. It takes a "local" `Rewrite t` and returns a global one. I only walk the tree once, there are no attempts to apply rewrites more than once per tree node until no more rewrites are possible.

However there are 2 ways to rewrite the tree. Each rewrite operates either on already rewritten subtree (`WithChildren` mode) or "original" subtree (`WithoutChildren` mode). In the latter case, the higher rewrite "wins".

Ignoring constraints on `t`, the type of `rewriteGlobal` is:

```
data ChildRewrites = WithChildren | WithoutChildren

rewriteGlobal :: ChildRewrites -> Rewrite t -> Rewrite t
```

Here is an implementation:

```
rewriteGlobal flag rewriteFn = para $ liftA2 (<|>)
    (rewriteFn . handleChildren flag)
    liftChildRewrites

handleChildren WithChildren = embed . fmap (uncurry fromMaybe)
handleChildren WithoutChildren = embed . fmap fst

liftChildRewrites cons | any (isJust . snd) cons = Just $ handleChildren WithChildren cons
liftChildRewrites _ = Nothing
```

`liftChildRewrites` and `liftA2 (<|>)` look particularly ugly.

The question is: cannot I do any better? The code is already short, so it's not about making it shorter. But am I heading in the right direction, or there are better approaches to distribution of local matches than a paramorphism, e.g. a better data structure, a monadic approach or a recursion scheme?

I don't have binders/names/capture avoiding substitutions, so (P)HOAS and similar approaches probably won't be any better. And I'm not implementing the SKI calculus, it's only a motivating example.

The following code can be used to test:

```
test = App I $ App S $ App I $ K

bar = [rewrite WithChildren match test, rewrite WithoutChildren match test]
```

The question is: are there any specific structures/methods designed for local rewrites? It's only opinion-based if such specialized approaches don't exist and general methods is the best I can do.